# Invalid constructor input for UpdateAlertPolicyRequest

Tags: python, google-cloud-monitoring, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to update an alert policy with Cloud Functions. I have the following lines of code:

```
filter = "resource.type = \"l7_lb_rule\" AND metric.type = \"logging.googleapis.com/user/stuff_here\"")
alert_policy = {"conditions":[{"condition_absent":{"duration": '1800s',"filter": '{}'.format(filter)}, "displayName":'test'}], "displayName":'test'), "combiner":"OR"}
policy = monitoring_v3.AlertPolicy.from_json(json.dumps(alert_policy))
client_alert.update_alert_policy(policy)
```

I'm running the same update with the API explorer and it's working. However the cloud functions return me this error `TypeError: Invalid constructor input for UpdateAlertPolicyRequest: display_name: "test"`

I'm also wondering where I should pass the name of the alert I want to update. I tried to pass the name as a parameters or the alert_policy object but it always return me some kind of errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing as argument of the `update_alert_policy` function something that, as you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/googleapis/python-monitoring/blob/b2f0a85fef585178dc5d89e7aebece4c444c15e4/google/cloud/monitoring_v3/services/alert_policy_service/client.py#L726) of the library is considered an `UpdateAlertPolicyRequest`, the first positional argument. You need to provide your information using the `alert_policy` argument instead, something like:

```py
# indicate every field you want to update and provide
# the corresponding values in the policy definition
mask = field_mask.FieldMask(paths=['display_name', 'combiner', 'conditions'])
policy = monitoring_v3.AlertPolicy(
    name='your_policy_name',
    display_name='test',
    combiner='OR',
    conditions=[
        monitoring_v3.types.AlertPolicy.Condition(
            display_name='test',
            condition_absent=monitoring_v3.types.AlertPolicy.Condition.MetricAbsence(
                duration='1800s',
                filter='resource.type = "l7_lb_rule" AND metric.type = "logging.googleapis.com/user/stuff_here"'
            )
        )
    ]
)
client.update_alert_policy(alert_policy=policy, update_mask=mask)
```

The library provides some [snippets](https://github.com/googleapis/python-monitoring/blob/main/samples/snippets/v3/alerts-client/snippets.py) that may be help.